# Subtraction between to excel column using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Suppose I have below excel sheet,And I need to find the difference between them and result need to put back to another column:

```
      ColA                      ColB                    ColC

9/3/2012  8:31:59 AM      09/17/2012  6:45:56 PM        Result
9/4/2012  8:31:59 AM      10/17/2012  6:45:56 PM        Result
```

I did it using Loop and Row-By-Row technique. Looking for a way if it can be done directly by column level subtraction. Say ColB-ColA - > ColC. The whole operation should be performed at a time.Result should come ***"hh:mm:ss"***.

***CODE***

```
  IntRow4=2
  Do While objSheet4.Cells(IntRow4,1).Value <> ""

    If objSheet4.Cells(IntRow4,9).Value <> "Open" Then

       Date1=objSheet4.Cells(IntRow4,7).Value
       Date2=objSheet4.Cells(IntRow4,8).Value
       objSheet4.Cells(IntRow4,11)=TimeSpan(Date1,Date2)

   End If

  IntRow4=IntRow4+1
  Loop
```

***Update***

```
      ColA1    ColB1      ColC1       ColA2    ColB2     ColC2   .....   ColAN    ColBN    ColCN    TotaltimeDurtion
      Date     Date     11:25:20      Date     Date     10:25:00          Date    Date     11:25:20      ?
```

***here i have shown only one row,But there can be multiple or N number of rows.What I need to do is,I want to add the time durations and put them to the last colum "TotaltimeDurtion".But the last column can not be fixed.And all the columns for each row shouldn't required values,but all never will be empty.Can we also do this also in column level.here the duration is hh:mm:ss format or as per your instruction [h]:mm:ss. TotaltimeDurtion <- ColC1  + ColC2 + ...+ ColCN.***

Comment: Why don't you want to use an Excel formula for this? `=B1-A1` and format as Time?

Comment: I will do it by my VBScript,the excel has no chance to set any such formula on it.All the columns are dynamic,so it should need to be calculated by script.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit You mentioned you need help on this question. It seems there are answers. Explain what you further need please?

Comment: @bonCodigo The answers here has been provided for only static sheet,for sheets where data are being populated by scripts,such function I can't put on any columns as a fixed,Thus I need somthing which can summed up the all durations at runtime!!

Comment: @bonCodigo you just tell me or give me a code by which I can add two durations which are `hh:mm:ss` rest I will set up.Please give me any quick such duration addition function.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit I remember one of the first codes that we (K_B, Larry, Me, or someone else perhaps) provided were adding up `hh:mm:ss` times. So what is again? :(

Comment: @bonCodigo That was a time duration between two columns.Now when individual durations calculation will be done,at last my script will perform the addition of those durations row wise and will save the result in the same format to `Totaltimespent` column!

Answer (score 2):

using the range object, I can set the formula on all the cells within a range at once

```
range("C1:C10").Formula="=B1-A1"
```

It will also adjust the formula based on the normal copying riles for absolute addressing.

e.g. with the above example, C10 will be `=B10-A10`. If I had put the formula as "=B1-$A$1" then C10 would have been `=B10-$A$1`

Comment: Yes,I agree.Thanks for your update.But let me know how then,the result column format would be selected as "hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: do the same thing with NumberFormat: `Range("C1:C10").NumberFormat="[h]:mm:ss"` (by using `[h]`, it allows up to 9999 hours, useful if something takes longer than 1 day)

Comment: Now I have one more question!

Comment: To sum every **N** th column: `=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(` **Your Range** `)-COLUMN(OFFSET(` **Your Range** `,,,1,1)),` **N** `)=0)` **Your Range** `)`. You should be able to use `COUNTA` to find out how many cells are filled in.

Comment: The time duration columns are not contiguous,they are simliarly looks like my description table having only one row. I wan to summed up all the duration and save it to the last column as in my description.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract one date from the other, and then set the formatting of the cell:

```
'Within the Do..While loop
Dim cell
Set cell = objSheet4.Cells(intRow4,11)
cell.Value = Date2 - Date1
cell.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
```

Comment: I was Looking for a solution by which I can directly Subtract 'ColB' - 'ColA' and set it to 'ColC', without taking care of Rows.Operation should be column level,not in Row Level.

Comment: Yes, it would still be iterating over the rows. I don't think it's possible to do at the column level.