# MINUS operation on Array elements

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have an Array say A=(11,23,32,44,56,88,55,14,78,79) And B=(44,56,88,55,14) .Now using VBScript can I perform Set operation ***MINUS*** to get an other output say C=(11,23,32,78,79)?

Array A and B can be considered also two Excel columns.

Don't want to use any Looping technique.

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's not a surprise that **Dictionaries** are the VBScript tool to implement (fake?) sets and operations on them. See [this Set demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6592801/603855).

BTW: If you have to deal with more than one thingy, you'll have to loop or ask someone else to loop for you. Insisting on "no loop, please" makes no sense. If 'it works', you may optimize by replacing multiple loops (n x m .. x z) by lookup tables or pre-computations, but you won't understand the problem, if you don't think of loopings.

Comment: any good idea from you on the below post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927207/subtraction-between-to-excel-column-using-vbscript/13928903#13928903

Answer (score 4):

No, vbs or vba cannot directly do a minus operation on two array ( no build-in function )
You must use loops
 and here is  a good reference for array operations in vba http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

Comment: +1 for pointing out loops as basic strategy for solving that kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Excel vba if u have named ranges `Acol` `Bcol`

```
Range("C3:C10").FormulaArray = "=Acol-Bcol"
```