# Array addition/subtraction vba

Tags: vba, math

Okay, I feel like I'm missing something major here; however I am trying to subtract arrays on VBA. I need to subtract the arrays and assign them to another variable `x` so I cant do a normalizing function. Below is my version of the code:

### Code:

```
Dim xnew As Variant, xTable As Variant, x As Variant

xnew = [{1,2}]
xTable = [{4,3}]

x = xTable - xnew

MsgBox (x)
```

I swear this is a stupid question and I have looked around the internet for this simple operation, but to my demise, nothing has come up... I see this question as different to [MINUS operation on Array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931786/minus-operation-on-array-elements) because the person asking here is trying to change the size of the array, I am not.

Comment: Check the answers in this thread [MINUS operation on Array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931786/minus-operation-on-array-elements). Looks like you will need named ranges or a loop. Does not seem like "array subtraction" is supported in vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to subtract them as a matrix. VBA isn't that smart. You need to loop through the array and do the subtraction yourself.

```
Dim xnew As Variant, xTable As Variant, x(1 To 2) As Variant, i As Integer

xnew = [{1,2}]
xTable = [{4,3}]

For i = LBound(xTable) To UBound(xTable)
    x(i) = xTable(i) - xnew(i)
Next

For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    Debug.Print "x(" & i & ") = " & x(i)
Next
```

**Output**

> x(1) = 3
>   x(2) = 1

Note: If you don't know the size of the `xTable` then you can do `ReDim x(LBound(xTable) To UBound(xTable)` to set the correct dimensions on `x`

Comment: Thanks! How do you know the output. It doesn't print it for me

Comment: @JakeK, open the VBA editor, and make sure you have the Immediate window visible (View → Immediate Window, CTRL+G). This is where `Debug.Print` output will show up.

Comment: Ah! Cool! I didn't know that was a feature! Thanks!

Comment: @JakeK, we honestly taught each other something new. I've been doing this for 15 years and I didn't know you could define an array like `[{element,element}]`

Comment: @DrewChapin `[]` is short hand for `Application.Evaluate` which can return an array.

Comment: Haha neato! That's awesome! I really hope it helps you out in the future!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use strings and `Application.Evaluate` to avoid the loop:

```
Dim xnew As String, xTable As String, x As Variant

xnew = "{1,2}"
xTable = "{4,3}"

x = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(" & xTable & " - " & xnew & ",)")

For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    Debug.Print "x(" & i & ") = " & x(i)
Next
```