# Is there any good way to make a non-contiguous array as contiguous 1D array?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Just out curiosity -Is there any good way to make a non-contiguous array as contiguous 1D array?

Say Arr(9)=(2,5,,,,25,14,,) to Arr(4)=(2,5,25,14)

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: Other than looping through and adding what is a value into a new array?

Comment: @ja72 yes,you are right!! Is there any?

Comment: I'd say no. Don't be afraid of the loops.

Comment: @ja72 if `Arraylist` I used can it be done? suppose Arr(9) is not an 1D array,but it is an `Arraylist`.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit can you take a look at the answer and comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How do you populate your array in the first place? If you are not trasposing a range directly into the array, then you may have a possibility of validating for empty cells and remove it from there, insated of doing it at a later stage.

Here is a loop based code to remove the empty items:

```
Dim Arr as Variant , vArr2 as Variant
Dim d as Object
Dim i as integer, j as integer

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'-- populate data array
vArr(1) = "10"
vArr(2) = "55"
vArr(3) = ""
vArr(4) = "27"
vArr(5) = ""

j = 1
For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    If vArr(i) <> "" Then
       d.Add vArr(i), j
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

'-- pass into a new array
vArr2 = d.Keys

'-- output into sheet
    Sheets(1).Range("B4").Resize(1, _
             UBound(Application.Transpose(d.Keys))) = d.Keys
```

Comment: Yes,you are right! the array will be populated by the range. Then what would be the approach?

Comment: @Tukai if 1D arrays are populated by ranges, there are couple of ways you may want to omit the empty cells. You could loop to remove empty cells - the most basic way. If put into a String all values, perhaps even a `Regex` could help.

Comment: how `Regex` need to use,no idea. Any help from your side!

Comment: Can you help me here also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927207/subtraction-between-to-excel-column-using-vbscript